# Falcon raising custom exception json

Tags: python, falconframework

When I raise `falcon.HTTPNotFound` I get following JSON

```
 {
    "title": "404 Not Found",
    "description": {
        "message": "Model mymodel does not exist!",
        "model_id": "mymodel"
    }
}
```

but instead of this I want to send across below

```
{
   "message": "Model mymodel does not exist!",
   "model_id": "mymodel"
}
```

how do I achieve this in Falcon?

```
def expect_model_existence(req, resp, resource, params, require_exists):

    model_id = params['model_id']

    if require_exists and not Model.exists(model_id=model_id):
        response = {"message": f"Model {model_id} does not exist!", "model_id": model_id}
        raise falcon.HTTPNotFound(description=response)
    elif not require_exists and Model.exists(model_id=model_id):
        response = {"message": f"Model {model_id} already exists!", "model_id": model_id}
        raise falcon.HTTPConflict(description=response)
```

Defined a function to check existence of Model and applied as before hook

```
@falcon.before(expect_model_existence, True)
    def on_delete(self, req, resp, model_id):
       pass
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I want to return response as JSON inside falcon.HTTPNotFound.

Comment: Do you see any error message?

Comment: no error, I am getting correct response but just need description part of total JSON object.